# Ubuntu 12.10 and Lenovo X1 HDMI output

Tags: hdmi, lenovo, samsung, intel-hd

I'm trying desperately to output HDMI from my laptop to my Samsung 40EH6030 LED TV.

I connected the HDMI1 on the TV to the computer, it shows that it detects the TV (40" Samsung Electric..) in the "Displays" section, on the TV I select that HDMI1 and I get "No signal".

It worked on the same computer while running Windows 7.

Any idea???

Answer (score 0):

Bring up the unity Dash and type Displays. Click on the icon for Displays and you should be able to choose your display from there.

Comment: did it, doesnt work